# Testing your roblox game in the studio acts differently than actually playing it outside of the studio

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I am trying to make a game in roblox studio. I do implement some features like swords that attack if you click. I use the test feature built in to roblox studio, and it works fine, but when I actually play it in roblox outside of the studio, it does not work. Why does the studio testing act differently than the game and what might cause it to work while testing but not work while playing? What are some scripting elements that do not work in roblox but work in the studio?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Roblox Developer Forum](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/roblox-scripts-not-working/521662/2):

> Hi, this is a very simple-to-fix issue.
>
> You must go to the View Section on Roblox Studio and then click drafts, there you’ll see all the scripts you have made changes to. Right-click and click "commit" to commit the changes and then you should publish to Roblox. This will fix your issue.
>
> Uncommitted scripts do not work outside of studio.

Therefore it is *not* website glitches or coding typos in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Either there's a problem with your script (especially if you put in a script that someone else made) which caused the website to glitch, or there's a problem with the handoff between studio and the website.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's the other way around (whether your game is published or not makes a big difference), but this might be a case of whether the values are taken from the website or not (that is to say, most "toolbox" items nowadays have reference to links in roblox, so it requires a good internet connection to properly function it). Or, there could be a glitch, your progress might not be saved. Or, due to the amount of people joining your server (whereas testing the game might usually just be yourself), there would be a malfunction in your script.

Comment: If the script couldn't even grab a tiny asset from the internet, then you would be disconnected anyways since a game requires more internet than that. Also, it's quite rare that the amount of players in the server is the cause since servers usually hold up to 10 players, but it may also depend on how many users are in all servers totaled. If Roblox itself glitched, then it would attempt to sync to the latest version of your game and give error 275 while doing so (usually). Of course, forgetting to press the "publish to Roblox" button also causes this, but I doubt that's the case here.